# Flash Touch Screen Application - Memory Leak

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

have developed a touch screen stand alone application. The interactive is currently running 10 - 13 hours per day. If the user interacts with interactive the memory level is going on increasing. The interactive has five screens while travelling through each screen I have removed the movieclip, assets, listener's and I set objects to null. Yet the memory level keep increasing.

Also I have used third party tool "gskinner" to solve this problem, It improves the result even though some memory leakage is there.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best results will come from writing the code in a way that elements are properly garbage collected on removal. That means removing all the objects, listeners and MovieClips/Sprites within that are no longer used.

When I'm trying to get this stuff done quickly, I've been using [casalib](http://casalib.org/)'s [CasaMovieClip](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_display_CasaMovieClip.html) and CasaSprite instead of regular MovieClips and Sprites. The reason is that they have the destroy() functions as well as some other functions that help you garbage collect easily.

But the best advice I can give is to read up on garbage collection. [Grant Skinner's blog](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check for setTimeout() and dictionaries, as these can cause leaks as well if not used properly.